# how can I remove the time-stamp from the contents of a log file

Tags: bash, scripting, debian

I have a log file where the log files line are prepended with the following time-stamp format:

%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S: (the last colon is intentional)

How can I remove the time-stamps using sed (would cat the log file through sed)? I have some experience with sed although I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be

edit: this is what the standard log line looks like:

2014-04-12_01:55:12:4391465 banned.

everything after '12:' should remain after the time-stamp has been removed

Thank you

Comment: are there any colons in the entry after the `..%S:`? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter yes there may be additional colons after '%S:' that are not part of time-stamp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to remove a fixed number of characters from the beginning of the line:

```
sed  's/^.\{20\}//' logfile
```

If your `sed` supports the `-r` option (for OSX, use `-E`), then the backslashes can be removed:

```
sed -r 's/^.{20}//' logfile
```

On your sample line, the above produces:

```
4391465 banned.
```

As long as the number of characters in the datestamp is fixed, one doesn't need `sed`.  `cut` would work as well:

```
cut -c21- logfile
```

#### Solution for a complex case

If the number of characters were not fixed, that is, if the numbers were not nicely zero-padded as yours are, then a more complex `sed` command would be in order like:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+[_:-]\)\{6\}//' logfile
```

The above looks for six sets of numbers followed by a separator and removes them.  Since your timestamp has six such sets (year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds), this does what you want.

Comment: haha had not thought of the fixed characters thing, would have been able to pull that one off on my own. Thanks!

Comment: While it looks like cut and sed are just as fast. cut is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have 3 colons you may as well use them as deliminators.

```
cut -d":" -f4 log.txt
```